# Not sure how to have my transition looped

Tags: jquery, transition, fadeto

I have created a little project where theres an image slideshow (transition) where on the page load, image opacities are changed, to create a slideshow effect.

It works really well, however I'm interested in knowing how I can upgrade my code so that it just loops back to the start, so the slideshow is never ending, Help will be greatly appreciated, here is what I have tried already:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#image1").fadeTo(2000 , 0, function() {
        $("#image2").fadeTo(2000 , 1, function(){
            $("#image3").fadeTo(3000, 1, function(){

            });
        });
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pYECC/4/

Comment: here is an update on my progress: http://jsfiddle.net/pYECC/6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres a nice little solution - http://jsfiddle.net/pYECC/7/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var images = ["image1", "image2", "image3"];
    var x = 0;

    setInterval(function () {
        $("#" + images[x]).fadeOut(1000, function () {
            x++;
            if(x == 3)
                x = 0;
            $("#" + images[x]).fadeIn(1000);
        });
    }, 3000);  
});
```

With this you need to remove opacity from your CSS. You need to make images 2 & 3 `display: none;` by default.

Comment: Hey, thanks for this solution however I have some problems with it, firstly it seems to start with the third image for some reason, and also the order in terms of the order it goes in changing the images seems to be wrong also, it goes from image3> image1> image2. and finally, it seems to stay on image 3 for so much longer then others. here is the updated link: http://jsfiddle.net/pYECC/12/

Comment: See update, you need to make images 2 & 3 display none - http://jsfiddle.net/pYECC/13/

Comment: Okay thanks, can you please explain to me how that is even looping? I really don't understand..

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>       
    var maxImgNum = null;
    var imgT = null;
    var transitionSpeed = 4000;
    var transitionDelay = 600;

    $(document).ready(function(){
        var $slideshowImgs = $("#anim_cont").find("img");
        var maxImgNum = $slideshowImgs.length;
        $slideshowImgs.each(function(i, obj){
            $(obj).css("z-index", maxImgNum - i);
    });
    imgT = window.setTimeout(function(){animateSlideshow()},transitionSpeed);          
});

function animateSlideshow(){

    $(".anim")
        .eq(0)
            .fadeOut(transitionDelay, function(){
                $(this).appendTo("#anim_cont")
                $(".anim").each(function(i, v){
                    $(this)
                        .css("z-index", maxImgNum-i)
                        .css("display", "block");
                })
                imgT = window.setTimeout(function(){animateSlideshow()}, transitionSpeed);

            });
}
</script>




<div id="anim_cont">
    <img src="http://eclipse-developers.com/download.jpg" id="image1" class="anim"/> 
    <img src="http://eclipse-developers.com/download2.jpg" id="image2" class="anim"/> 
    <img src="http://eclipse-developers.com/download3.jpg" id="image3" class="anim"/> 
</div>
```

Comment: This creates a nice morphing effect, transitioning from one image to the other.  It's a technique utilized on many pages created by Google and Apple.  It also has many benefits such as no no direct references to the images themselves.  Therefore, you can seperate the JS into another file and minify it and not have to worry if you need to add or subtract to you slideshow in the future.  Secondly, it allows low level programmers or designers to easily update the page.  In this solution you would also need to remove "opacity" references in css.

Comment: yeah its fine, but sadly it doesn't fit into what I need, please take a look at the first slideshow on this link: www.teamgeek.co.za/                                                 see how it fades? so that part of the old image is sort of merged and it looks like a transition, instead of just one image disappears then another comes in.

Comment: Panda you must not have tried the code.  That is exactly what happens, one image fades out while the other fades in - looking as though they are for a brief period merged.  This is the methodology used by Google, Apple, and other major website.  In addition to the other benefits I already listed, if you choose to create a slideshow with like 100 elements, you could asynchronously load a few at a time making slight modifications to my code above.  That way a crazy amount of memory does not have to be utilized to store all the images at once.  Trust me this is the way to go - you should try it.

Comment: `window.setTimeout(function(){animateSlideshow()}, transitionSpeed)` can be changed to `window.setTimeout(animateSlideshow, transitionSpeed)` both times it is used. You don't need an anonymous function.

Comment: Yes mcrumley is correct, originally I had other code in the anon function and I should have put that shortcut.  May still be useful if someone made modifications to this code and needed to pass in some parameters.  Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: nope, im looking at it on my screen now, thats not the effect im seeing. infact, take a look your self - http://jsfiddle.net/9uq3a/

Comment: In the filddle you should remove display:none and implement mcrumley's suggestion.  The general idea is that you can achieve a smooth blended transition by only fading out the top layer.  Here are some examples: http://goo.gl/ieSOjh or http://goo.gl/L3KQc.  This prevents it from momentarily fading to white but I guess that's what you want my mistake.  Just trying to help you out maybe it will assist someone else.  BTW, I don't know who downvoted your question to a -1, but I was the one who upvoted you to raise it back to 0 since I thought you had a legit question and it was unfair.  Take Care.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap all the slideshow transitions into a function, and then pass that function as the callback to the last transition. That would cause it to loop indefinitely.

Alternatively, you could use CSS animations to achieve this effect, as they natively support looping and browsers can often better optimize them for performance vs script-based transitions. You could then [detect browser support for CSS animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_animations/Detecting_CSS_animation_support) and fall back to the jQuery transitions if support is missing.